# jQuery Post blob object gives Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, blob

I am trying to post a file using jQuery `post`, and get `TypeError: Illegal invocation`

```
function fbUpload(token){
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0)
  var blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURL)

  $.post( "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos", {
    'access_token': token,
    'source': blob
  }, function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Could it be because of the 'blob'?

This is working fine:

```
function fbUpload(token){
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0)
  var blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURL)
  var formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('access_token', token)
  formData.append('source', blob)

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open( 'POST', 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos', true )
  xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = function() {
    console.log( xhr.responseText )
  };
  xhr.send( formData )
}
```

Comment: tried `$.post( "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos", formData ...` got the same error

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ilyador/pLxpyvc8/1/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use `$.ajax` and provide the `FormData` object to the `data` parameter. `$.post` only takes data as a string or as a plain object. Try this:

```
function fbUpload(token){
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0)
    var blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURL)
    var formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('access_token', token)
    formData.append('source', blob)

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos", 
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `contentType: false` prevents $.ajax from setting a content type header. Which will allow the underlying xmlhttprequest to set the content type to multipart form data with the correct **boundary**