# Upload file using jQuery AJAX is not working in ASP.NET Core MVC v3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

> Important note: I'm getting suggestions to follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872448/jquery-post-blob-object-gives-uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation) to be
> able to resolve my issue. But, I'm already doing whatever has been
> suggested in this post.

I'm following [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/questions/130814/Upload-Form-data-and-File-in-ASPNet-Core-using-jQuery-Ajax/) article and trying to upload Image file to server using jQuery AJAX. I'm trying to find a way to get all the details inside `UploadFileUsingJQueryAJAX` action method of `HomeController` under the `emp` parameter

Below is the code in `HomeController`:

```
    public IActionResult UploadFileUsingJQueryAJAX()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UploadFileUsingJQueryAJAX(Employee emp)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Below is the code in `UploadFileUsingJQueryAJAX` view

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Upload File Using jQuery AJAX";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<form id="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="UploadFileUsingJQueryAJAX" asp-controller="Home">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Photo:</td>
            <td><input type="file" id="photo" name="postedFile" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Photo:</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="AjaxFormSubmit();" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/js/upload_file_using_jquery_ajax_script.js"></script>
}
```

Below is the `Employee` class which is inside Models folder.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public string FistName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the required javascript inside `upload_file_using_jquery_ajax_script.js`

```
function AjaxFormSubmit() {
    var url = $('#myForm').attr('action');
    var firstName = $('#txtFirstName').val();
    var lastName = $('#txtLastName').val();
    var photo = $('#photo')[0].files[0];

    var model = {
        url: url,
        FirstName: firstName,
        LastName: lastName,
        Photo: photo
    };

    SubmitForm(firstName, lastName, photo);
}

function SubmitForm(firstName, lastName, photo) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/UploadFileUsingJQueryAJAX',
        data: {
            FirstName: firstName,
            LastName: lastName,
            Photo: photo
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response.responseText);
            if (response.status == "success") {
                //alert("File : " + response.filename + " is uploaded successfully");
                console.log(response.responseText);
            }
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("Error occurs" + err.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm getting below error in Browser's console window when executing the program.

[image]

Values were not passed to controller action method. After some modifications, looks like something went wrong. The Controller action method is not even hitting.

After some analysis, found [this article](https://codepedia.info/ajax-file-upload-aspnet-core-razor-pages) and changed the code accordingly. But, no luck.

Tried to resolve the issue by following some web resources like [this](https://mtsknn.fi/blog/illegal-invocations-in-js/), [this](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872448/jquery-post-blob-object-gives-uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation) but no luck.

Can someone help me to resolve the issue! Actually,  as per the requirement I have to upload and read Excel file. But I'm trying in this program to upload Image file as I'm getting almost all the articles on uploading images only and I want to align with the article while learning and understanding the concept. Please let me know if I need to follow some addtional steps that I need to follow if I need to upload and read Excel file from Controller action method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Post blob object gives Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872448/jquery-post-blob-object-gives-uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation)

Comment: Hi @Natrium: Already verified this post before I posted this question in stackoverflow. There's nothing to takeout from this post for my issue.

Comment: _"I'm already doing whatever has been suggested in this post."_... no you're not. Where's your `FormData` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `FormData` to upload file in ajax and add configurations like:

```
processData: false,
contentType: false,
```

Please refer to this code:

```
function AjaxFormSubmit() {
        var url = $('#myForm').attr('action');
        var firstName = $('#txtFirstName').val();
        var lastName = $('#txtLastName').val();
        var formData = new FormData()
        formData.append("FirstName",firstName);
        formData.append("LastName", lastName);
        formData.append("Photo", $('#photo')[0].files[0]);

        SubmitForm(formData);
    }

    function SubmitForm(FormData) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/UploadFileUsingJQueryAJAX',
            data: FormData,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response.responseText);
                if (response.status == "success") {
                    //alert("File : " + response.filename + " is uploaded successfully");
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("Error occurs" + err.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Demo:

[image]

BTW: you wrote `FirstName` as `FistName` in Employee.